# Lua Scripting and C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, scripting, lua

this is quite tricky for me and i'm hoping someone can help me out.

The situation: I'm currently working an application in C# 3.5 .NET , it interfaces with a DLL written in C++ using DLL Imports, that all works fine. I also have a Lua script, this script is as follows:

```
Width           = XCamera():GetWidth()
Height          = XCamera():GetHeight()
Img             = XSensorImage()
```

then for example, there is a function that calculates the temperature from Img by:

```
function OnFrame()
     local CoordsTable = { i, j }
     local PixelTable = Img:GetPixels( CoordsTable )
     PixelValue = FromLinearizedADU( PixelTable[1] or 0 )
end
```

what I want to be able to do, is return PixelValue to my application.

XCamera() & XSensorImage() are instances created when the camera filters are initialized and the Lua script is active.

Is there anyway of accessing Pixel Value from this script when it is running? 
I'm sorry if I'm not being detailed enough, please ask if you require more, your feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return the PixelValue from the function.

```
return PixelValue;
```

Comment: Yes however, the script is called by an image filter, so it is run internally by an image filter on the camera, is there any way to send that value to a windows form? or maybe drop it into some memory?

Answer (score 0):

Is the C++ DLL hosting the Lua runtime, and not your C# app? Then, no, there's probably no easy way to do that. If the DLL is using a shared Lua DLL and doesn't have extensions locked down, you could potentially load a library that uses some form of interprocess communication to communicate back to the C# app.

Comment: The C# app calls a function in the C++ DLL which deals with the script, so I don't think there's any easy way around this!